# Is it possible to give a class and title lowercase letters with JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

Is it possible to give a class and title lowercase letters with JQuery or JavaScript?

I have this code:

```
<span class="status-source sources-detailed-{{ticket.source_name}}" title="{{ticket.source_name}}"></span>
```

And you see this when you look at the website with element inspection:

```
<span class="status-source sources-detailed-Phone" title="Phone"></span>
```

I want everything to be lowercase, so like this:

```
<span class="status-source sources-detailed-phone" title="phone"></span>
```

I searched the internet but did not come across any solutions.

I use Freshdesk to make this site, so I cannot adjust the strings myself. That is why I am now looking for another way

Freshdesk uses the Liquid Templating Engine.

Comment: You need to convert the string to lowercase in the value of `ticket.source_name`, not JS

Comment: You can just lowercase the variable. 
**ticket.source_name.toLowerCase()**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Freshdesk uses the Liquid Templating Engine.

Comment: Your first step should always be [**the documentation**](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't know which engine they used until you asked, thanks for the documentation. This is going to help me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Freshdesk uses the Liquid Templating Engine.

The Liquid Template Engine allows you to apply filters to your values:

https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/downcase/

```
{{ "Parker Moore" | downcase }}
```

So your example becomes:

```
<span class="status-source sources-detailed-{{ticket.source_name | downcase}}" 
      title="{{ticket.source_name | downcase}}"></span>
```